# How to insert a character inside a string

Tags: php, insert, replace

```
$string=apple
$add=£
$new=app£le
```

I am facing problem with inserting character in a string.

Comment: More ideas for further help: [How to insert a string inside another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372737/how-to-insert-a-string-inside-another-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string='apple';
$add='£';
$new=substr_replace($string,$add,3,0);
echo $new;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would split the string into two at the desired point, and then concatenate it back together with the new character added in.

I would give more detail, but I don't know what your intended splitting rules are.

Comment: i need insert  character into string then 3. character Example:melon>mel£on , banana>ban£ana , orange>ora£nge